# Creating Sqlite Tables In Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I try to create three tables in a database but it only creates tbl_alarms, tbl_bookmarks and android_metadata. Why can't I create tbl_locationfrommap ?

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Informations.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'tbl_alarms'", null);

    if(cursor.getCount()==0) {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_ALARMS = "CREATE TABLE tbl_alarms (" + 
                                               "alarmName TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                               " distance INTEGER, 
                                                 ringtone TEXT, 
                                                 vibrate INTEGER, 
                                                 latitude INTEGER, 
                                                 longitude INTEGER, 
                                                 note TEXT, 
                                                 alarmTime LONG, 
                                                 alarmSnoozeTime LONG);";
        final String CREATE_TABLE_BOOKMARKS = "CREATE TABLE tbl_bookmarks (" +
                                              "bookmarkName TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                              "latitude INTEGER, 
                                               longitude INTEGER);";
        final String CREATE_TABLE_MAPLOCATION = "CREATE TABLE tbl_locationfrommap (" +
                                                "latitude INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+
                                                " , longitude INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ALARMS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BOOKMARKS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MAPLOCATION);
    }
```

Comment: you can have only 1 primary key per table.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one **PRIMARY KEY** in table. you have added two primary keys while creating table.

I suggest you to modify it as follows,

```
final String CREATE_TABLE_MAPLOCATION = "CREATE TABLE tbl_locationfrommap (" +  " latitude INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+" , longitude INTEGER UNIQUE );";
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic sql problem.
Change sql from

CREATE TABLE tbl_locationfrommap (" +  " latitude INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+" , longitude INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)

to

CREATE TABLE tbl_locationfrommap (" +  " latitude INTEGER"+" , longitude INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(latitude, longitude))

When if you intent to create pair primary keys

Answer (score 0):

In table you can only assign one **Primary Key** .

**Create one another field id and make it primary and remove it from latitude and longitude.**

```
final String CREATE_TABLE_MAPLOCATION = "CREATE TABLE tbl_locationfrommap (" + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+  " latitude INTEGER"+" , longitude INTEGER );";
```